# Create a ameasure for slicing Fact Tables without active relationchip

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

Hello everyone,

I have two fact tables and I want to add a slicer for filtring location in both tables, I have the attributes (Loc) Location VMI Flag it a binary variables (O is Located, 1 : no located) exists on two fact tables, thus I create a table with field ALL locations containing two values Locations and No location and ths second attribute is Index with O or 1.
My Question: can I create a measure that slice dynamically the two fact tables without active relationship.?

Comment: Filtering requires relationships.  Sometimes you need to create a new single column to relate the tables.

Comment: Yes in the Fact tables I have column location with 0 and 1
0 : Located 
1 : Not Located

Comment: @DavidBrowne could I create a measure with Index columns and Location VMI Flag?

Comment: Not a measure, but a calculated column, or Custom Column in Power Query that concatenates the two columns into one.

Comment: @DavidBowne if I create a calculate column in the dimension table can I slicer the fact table without a relationship in the model?

Comment: No.  Relationships define filter flow.  That’s what the are for.  Why wouldn’t you want to add relationships?